# MySql insert statement driving me nuts

Tags: mysql

This is my Create table script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_beats`;
CREATE TABLE  .`wp_beats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `upload_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `genre_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my Insert Statement:

```
 INSERT INTO `wp_beats` (name, user_id, filename, extension, duration, upload_date_time) VALUES ("Anthony test beat", "1", "4eaab724745ee", ".mp3", " 00:04:13.88", "2011-10-28 14:08:07")
```

And I get this error in mysql browser:

```
Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine
```

Do you find any fault in any of the statement?

**EDIT:**

**I dropped the table and created a new one with the above script and now it's working. This is really funny. God knows what will happen when this happens in production environment!**

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36411 - I think it's a known bug. Try explicitly naming the auto inc field in the insert statement, and setting the value to "null".

Comment: What version of MySQL and what platform?  There is at least one [InnoDB bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35602) that leads to that error message.

Comment: I copied and pasted the statements into a test db and didn't get an error; perhaps you have a corrupt table?  Google for how to check and repair one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two options:
either http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36411 or you already out of int(11)

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have in your insert is that you are not inserting `genre_id` even though the table doesn't accept NULL values; **BUT** the error message you are getting it's weird. I'm not sure this is the issue. Try inserting something for `genre_id` and see what happens.

Comment: true but even after giving genre_id it didn't work. I had to drop the table and recreate a new one. I have this behavior 1st time even though I worked with MS SQL, Oracle and MySql.

Comment: @Anthony it definitely looks like a mysql bug or a table corruption. That's why I put that big BUT; because I didn't think that was necessarily the problem you are facing at this time although your query definitely had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a bug opened in mysql about this situation. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35602  What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: I am using latest version of wamp which has MySql 5.5.16

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a [MySQL Bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35602).